# Not disconnecting from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Android 4.4.2 on Moto X. I have a custom bluetooth low energy board, which has a red LED turned on when no devices connected to it. It supports just one connected device at a time. I am building an Android application that tries to connect to this BLE device and writes to its characteristic and then disconnects from it. I am having two problems: after writing a value to characteristic, I am doing:

```
mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
mBluetoothGatt.close();
mBluetoothGatt = null;
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
```

but that doesn't actually disconnect my smartphone (the LED on BLE device remains turned off, meaning that some device is still connected to it). However, when I turn off the bluetooth adapter on my smartphone, the LED immediately turns on.

The second problem is that I can't write to my characteristic from the first attempt, I have to call the same sequence for the second time.

Here's the procedure that is called to write my characterictic:

```
public void trytounlock() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    if (connect("E2:0C:B9:4D:B9:56"))
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "connect returned true!");
    }
    else {
        Log.w(TAG, "connect returned false - warum?");
    };
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null ) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
     else
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter initialized successfully!");
    }
    if ( mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "GATT not initialized");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "GATT initialized succesfully!");
    }

    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000f00d-1212-efde-1523-785fef13d123"));
    while (!mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices())
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Waiting for service discovery");
    }
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found here. ");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service found successfully!");
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000beef-1212-efde-1523-785fef13d123"));
    byte[] raw={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}; 
        mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(raw);
    if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to write characteristic - ошибочка!!", duration).show();
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized, while trying to disconnect - weird!!!");
    }
    else {
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }
    mWriteCharacteristic = null;
    mCustomService = null;
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
    }
    else {
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
}
```

Here's my connect procedure:

```
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
     if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}


// Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
// connection change and services discovered.
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

So, the questions are:

1. How to release my board properly, so that is sees no other devices connected to it?
2. What is the reason it only write my characteristic, when I call it for the second time after I initially turn on the bluetooth adapter?

Comment: You need to make your flow callback based. You can't just put all steps in sequence. For example, when you get onServicesDiscovered you should write your characteristic and in onCharacteristicWrite you can perform your disconnect.

Comment: Emil, I just tried to implement that approach, but now my onCharacteristicWrite is not called for whatever reason. (I used Log.d to track that moment, but I can't see my custom message in logcat, so I believe, it is not called). However, judging by the device, the characteristic nevertheless is written!

Comment: eh) when I added this checkup after writing to characteristic if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false) - suddenly everything started working as intended (at least it seems to) - thank you!

Comment: okay. now i've got another challenge: i uploaded the app to a newer system (API25 it says) - although it returns connect status okay, I never get into  callbacks... :-(  do I have to build two separate versions of an app: for kitkat and for lollipop?